# Javascript function, objects

Tags: javascript

I got an object defined global way:

```
window.myobj = {};
```

Then new elements are being added and finally it is being saved via ajax to database by `SaveData(obj)` function. The problem is, that I am making it alot of times in short period, and it seems that what is being passed to function is only a pointer to one single object, so when another event occures, it changes inside a save function even when it was changed outside. In PHP, you have to use `&$obj` for it... so how do I do it properly, so the obj passed to the function would not be only a pointer?

Edit:
The problem appeared in here:

Lets say that `event = {time:123,type:blah}`

```
function SaveData(event){
  obj = jQuery.extend({}, event); // doesn't seem to replicate event
  $.post('save',obj,function(res){
    if(res) console.log(obj);
  });
  if(obj.type == 'blah'){
     newobj = jQuery.extend({}, obj);
     newobj.type = 'newtype';
     newobj.time = 234;
     SaveData(newobj);
  }else if(obj.type == 'newtype'){
     newobj = jQuery.extend({}, obj);
     newobj.type = 'lasttype';
     newobj.time = 345;
     SaveData(newobj);  
  }
}
```

This returns 3 objects that are the same:

```
{time:345,type:lasttype}
```

Comment: Could you post more of your code so that we know how you access / pass around the object?

Comment: What function? Why is it relevant? The object is already global, what's the point passing it around to functions? Sorry, but your question is very unclear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Comment: @ShadowWizard edited, explained.

Comment: The weird thing is that it does save different objects, but writes the same...

Comment: Because `obj` is global and at the moment you are calling `console.log(obj)`, you are getting the value of `obj` from the last call to `SaveData`. However, when you pass the object to `$.post`, it gets evaluated immediately. It doesn't seem that `obj` must be global anyways. Just make it local.

Comment: Oh! because `obj = ''` in function makes it global, and `var obj = ''` makes it local! Good to know that...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Object `myobj` does not contain any functions, but only values and further objects, one very easy way to clone the Object (and thus get rid of the problem with pointers) would be:

```
var clonedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window.myobj));
```

Now you can pass the `clonedObj` to your `SaveData` Function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, the answer is as simple as;

```
var myCopy = $.extend(true, {}, window.myobj);
```

If not, this function will create a deep copy the object - including functions and nested objects;

```
function clone(original) {

    if (original == null || typeof(original) !== 'object')
        return original;

    var theClone = original.constructor.call(this);

    for (var property in original) {
        theClone[property] = clone(original[property]);
    }

    return theClone;

}
```

Comment: @FlashThunder - you'd want to pass in `true` as first parameter to extend, to create a deep copy, depending on your objects.

Comment: it is simple 2d object... but the problem is that it doesn't seem to work at all, still refers to the same object, as in given example...